# Not sure if my rails application is configured properly for posrtgres db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**My problem**: I have setup the dev, test environments of my Rails application to use the postgresql database. Now how do I verify that it is ok?

Note: I am beginner on Rails and using databases

**What I've did to verify**

1. I followed the [railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql) to migrate from default sqlite3 to postgresql.
2. I fired up the rails console and created a user using

   User.create(name: "Anil Bande", email: "anil@gmail.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
3. From the output it looked like the user was created. To verify I ran `$ User.all` while on the rails console and the output displayed the object I'd created in step (2)
4. Now I wanted to see this from postgresql prompt. So I did `$psql sample_app_development` and there came the psql prompt.
5. I did a `psql>> \d` on the psql to list all the tables in the database. It did and the table "users" was also present in which I was interested in.
6. Now I did a `psql>> select * from users` , but there were no results. The prompt just returned back.

Now here is my confusion. Step (6) showing nothing. But in rails console it looks like the user is created and saved in the database. 
(a) Why so? 
(b) How do I verify everything I have done to setup the dev and test environment is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment on the Rails part, but for this:

> Now I did a psql>> select * from users , but there were no results. The prompt just returned back.

You forgot to end the statement with a `;`

You need to tell psql when you are finished typing a statement, as it is allowed to have a statement span more than one line. Note how the prompt changed from `psql=>` to `psql->` to indicate that psql is waiting for more.

So if you enter

```
psql=> select * from users;
```

you should be fine.

(Just to be clear: *psql* as part of the prompt is only an example. The real prompt will contain the name of the database you are connected to. The important thing to look for is the `=>` and `->`)

Comment: Damn! I knew it must be something trivial. Thanks for answering my first question

Answer (score 0):

Have you run your migration on the DB yet in the console?

```
rake db:migrate
```

If so, also make sure that your database config yml file has the correct info with ->

user, password, localhost etc listed for your databases like

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: pg2_development
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: root
  host: localhost
```

--> run rails server , than goto localhost:3000/user to check results

Answer (score 0):

If you are just getting started with postgres you may find your general admin better served using a GUI interface like [pgadmin](http://Www.pgadmin.org)

For example it would tell you that the end ';'  was missing. It still allows you to go directly to a psgl command line.